# How to make logical model using oracle data modeler?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, data-modeling

So i made a STUDENT Schema and wanted to know how to make logical model using the oracle data modeler. I have never used the oracle data modeler. thank you

Comment: Your questions seems to be off-topic as StackOverflow states: "... question asking for a ..., tutorial... seems to be off-topic."

Comment: i dont understand "off topic"..how is it off topic?

Comment: We follow here a series of rules to post. Your question is off topic because you are asking to teach you how to use some software so it fits on the rule: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` Read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question to a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot make a *logical model* from a *physical* schema.

A logical model is a representation of the business logic, and is primarily a communication tool.  It may contain duplications or constructs such as many-to-many relationships which we would wish to avoid in our actual database.  Likewise it should omit things which aren't part of the business domain (surrogate keys, date created columns, etc).

It is my experience that people don't really understand the difference between logical and physical models, and so rarely get real benefits from building a logical model.  A logical model derived directly from a physical implementation just echoes back the assumptions and compromises baked into the database schema.  A genuine logical model will support multiple potential implementations.

However, Oracle Data Modeler does allow us to reverse engineer a physical model from the database data dictionary.  Furthermore it does support the reverse engineering of a logical model from a physical model.  So there is a two-step process available, if you really want to avoid creating a logical model from scratch.

Oracle's web site has a decent tutorial on this.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldevdm/r30/datamodel2moddm/datamodel2moddm.htm)